# Como alterar transparência do Linear Layout

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma tela de login que tem um `LinearLayout` com fundo azul tranparente. Como posso fazer esse `LinearLayout` com id ser translúcido?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.teste.testenotification.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="100dp">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/corTransparente"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <EditText

            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Usuario"
            />

        <EditText
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/login"
            android:hint="Senha"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode colocar uma transparência na cor de fundo, ao invés de usar o **colorPrimary**

Veja essa lista aonde tem a lista de transparências:

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

Então por exemplo, se você quiser colocar um fundo azul com 50% de transparência, ficaria dessa forma:

```
android:background="#800000FF"
```

O **0000FF** é referente a cor azul, e o **80** na frente indica os **50%** de transparência

Comment: Ops, não vi que você tinha respondido. Boa resposta! Toma meu +1

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de:

```
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
```

Coloque:

```
android:background="#CC000000"
```

Isso é um preto em hexadecimal com um 80% de transparência. Para colocar transparência, basta definir os dois primeiros dígitos de um hexadecimal.

```
[CC][000000] ----> Cor
  |     
  +--> Transparência
```

Veja abaixo algumas um exemplo de outro percentual de transparência:

```
0%   -> #00 
25%  -> #40
50%  -> #80
75%  -> #C0
100% -> #FF
```

Comment: Amigo é que a cor precisa ser essa mas ela precisa ser transparente porque terá uma imagem atrás...

Comment: Me ajuda.......

Comment: @aline Você tem que entrar em @color/colorPrimary e ver qual é o hexadecimal dela. Aí é só inserir na frente no lugar do preto que coloquei =D

Comment: Entendi amigo. Obrigada...Mas a outra resposta eu achei mais simples de entender de imediato... Oo...

Comment: @Aline Sem problema! Eu votei na outra resposta também por estar bem explicada. Boa sorte ai. =D

Comment: Valeu amigo...     :D